# scanimage does not find scanner unless sudo'ed, but shows up with sane-find-scanner (Raspbian)

Tags: debian, raspbian, scanner, sane

I have an Epson multifunction device connected to a Raspberry Pi running the latest Raspbian. As you can see in the output below, scanimage will only find my scanner if I sudo it, but sane-find scanner finds it just fine without sudo. I've checked that the device permissions are properly set... saned is a memeber of the lp group, which is the group of the USB device. What gives?

```
richard@raspberrypi ~ $ scanimage > image.pnm
scanimage: no SANE devices found

richard@raspberrypi ~ $ sane-find-scanner

...

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0839) at libusb:001:004
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0424, product=0xec00) at libusb:001:003

...

richard@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo scanimage > image.pnm

richard@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo su -s /bin/bash - saned
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
No directory, logging in with HOME=/

saned@raspberrypi:/$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04b8:0839 Seiko Epson Corp. CX8300/CX8400/DX8400

saned@raspberrypi:/$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001
total 0
crw-rw-r-T  1 root root 189, 0 Feb 12 02:23 001
crw-rw-r-T  1 root root 189, 1 Jan  1  1970 002
crw-rw-r-T  1 root root 189, 2 Jan  1  1970 003
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root lp   189, 3 Feb 12 02:24 004

saned@raspberrypi:/$ groups
saned lp scanner
```

Comment: fwiw, I had a very similar symptoms, and it turned out that the firmware file installed by myself was readable by root only. Adding read permissions for ”other“ users: voilá, problem solved. (It's a firmware file with .nal file extension. The scanner is by Fujitsu, sane-epijitsu sane backend.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved my problem, thanks to the tutorial found here:

http://www.johndstech.com/2016/linux/raspberry-pi/geek-friday-setting-up-epson-scanning-on-raspberry-pi/

I had to create /etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules to say:

```
SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

and /etc/saned/epson2.conf to reflect the vendor and product ID:

```
usb <0x04b8> <0x0839>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of the Canon TS3150 , the above solution was not enough.

1. Removing all previous installations.
2. [Fresh download from Canon](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts3151.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20(64-bit)#disclaimer) and installation from the given `install.sh`
3. Adding that line in a rule.d/55-whatever.rules
4. Adding usb 0x04a9 0x1782   on /etc/sane.d/canon.conf
5. Restarting udev service with `udevadm control --reload-rules;udevadm trigger`.

Still, `sane-find-scanner` reports the scanner, but `scanimage -L` not

Then, in a [french forum for ubuntu](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2021510), I read that they do not use the normal programs, but a special one that comes with the Canon driver.

The `scangearmp2` was installed and ran. Amazing but Canon prefers their own simplistic program than any SANE-based one.